# Не отображается pdf файл на клиенте

Tags: javascript, java

на сервере:

```
connected = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
    response.setContentType("Document");

    response.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=3600, must-revalidate");
    response.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,"filename="+ "forPrint.pdf");

    response.setContentLength(connected.length);
    response.setCharacterEncoding(StringPool.UTF8);
    out.write(connected);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
```

на клиенте хочется как-то распарсить, но при открытии нового окна с со ссылкой на этот код, открывается окно, но pdf файл в нем не отображается, при этом если кликнуть по окну правой кнопкой, то файл можно сохранить.

Как открыть в новом окне так, чтобы файл отображался?

Comment: сам файл pdf файл. хочу загрузить его на клиент, чтобы потом отправить на печать. ContentType забыл закоменить(
В том что делаю не уверен, смотрел примеры в интернетах, делал как там.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
> response.setContentType("Document");

- Во-первых, вы дважды выставляете заголовок `Content-Type`, и второй затирает первый.
- Во-вторых, что такое `"Document"`?
- В-третьих, `Content-Disposition` обычно выставляют, чтобы вынудить браузер сразу сохранять файл, вместо попытки отобразить его. Вы уверены, в том, что делаете?